# What is the sd-shell in the nuclear shell model?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I understand that the energy levels in the nuclear shell model go as:

$$1S_{1/2}, 1P_{3/2}, 1P_{1/2}, 1D_{5/2}, 2S_{1/2}, 1D_{3/2}$$

But what is meant by the "sd-shell"? Is it something to do with the 2S and 1D shells overlapping?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide your present education level? I'll try to answer accordingly.

Comment: I am at Masters level. ZeroTheHero's answer was enough for me to figure out what I needed but a more complete answer may prove useful for other users of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look up the angular momentum of the 3D harmonic oscillator, which often approximates the nuclear potential.  The states are exactly degenerate in the h.o. approximation.  The $n=2$ states have $\ell=0$ (i.e. $s$ states) and $\ell=2$ ($d$ states).  See also [this energy diagram](https://images.app.goo.gl/Z3hwqrX7GcUx2rhL7) for the shell model, which illustrates the near degeneracy and labelling of the states in a shell.